# ¿De dónde viene la exclamación "yupi"?

Tags: etimología, interjecciones

Según el diccionario:

> **[yupi](http://dle.rae.es/?id=cE6n9aZ)**
>
> 1. interj. U. para expresar júbilo.

A veces podemos encontrar textos en los que alguien exclama "¡Yupi!" para denotar alegría. Sin embargo, debe de ser una voz muy reciente porque en el NTLLE no aparece en ningún diccionario anterior. El DRAE tampoco se aventura a dar una etimología.

El texto más antiguo del CORDE es el siguiente:

> *Nina (Tirando su gorro por el aire.): ¡Yupi! Qué suerte. Acostarse tan tempranito...*
>
> Antonio Gala, "Los verdes campos del Edén", 1963 (España)

Y buscando en Ngram encontré un texto de 1959 que, curiosamente, dice:

> *Nada de eso: era sencillamente que Fruto estaba contento, y empleaba la exclamación anglosajona «¡Yupi!» para exteriorizar su alegría.*
>
> Álvaro de Laiglesia, "Obras I".

¿Es realmente importada del inglés la expresión "yupi"? ¿O tiene algún otro origen? ¿Tendrá algo que ver con la exclamación "yippee-ki-yay"?

Comment: ¿No vendrá de [_Los mundos de Yupi_](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Los_mundos_de_Yupi)?

Comment: @fedorqui Podría parecer, pero esa serie se estrenó en 1988, y los textos mencionados son anteriores. Lo mismo pasa con la palabra inglesa _[yuppie](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuppie)_ para designar a los jóvenes ejecutivos, se creó en los 80, así que tampoco pueden tener relación.

Comment: Pues siguiendo con el hilo de _yippee-ki-yay_ que indicas en la pregunta, veo que [_yippee_](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=yippee) como interjección en inglés ya data de 1920. Por cierto, en España es conocida, será interesante ver si nuestros compañeros de Hispanoamérica también la usan.

Comment: Is _yupi_ still used? My impression is that yippee is not so common these days in English. Strange that it did not preserve the sound, I assume _yipi_ would have been better.

Comment: No me arriesgo a asegurarlo, pero podría venir también de [_whoopee_](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=whoopee).

Comment: @mdewey no, it is very seldom used, and it sounds as an expression for small kids. Also, sometimes adults use it in a sarcastic way.

Comment: Creo que no existe un origen como tal. Es una expression onomatopéyica que según la cultura aparece con diferentes formas. Los hispanos decimos ¡yupi!, los _cowboys gringos_  dicen `Yeehaw!!!. Debe haberse formado igual que ¡epa! ¡upa!

Comment: @fedorqui No lo parece.  Esa expresión es bastante anterior.

Answer (score 4):

Acabo de toparme con [este artículo](http://www.fotolog.com/ivanzuelo/18564538/) que explica:

> **YUPI**: Parece ser que esta forma deriva del inglés *jumpy* formado a partir del verbo *to jump* que significa "saltar". En principio, cuando se exclamaba esta palabra, el hablante brincaba de repente, levantando los brazos, expresando con este gesto su júbilo y la admiración hacia algo sorprendente, divertido, inesperado o fantástico. Puede aparecer en su variante más castellana "¡Chupi!".

Dos *caveats* importantes acerca del artículo es que no menciona la fuente sobre la que basa esa afirmación. Aparte, aunque algunas de las etimologías u orígenes de las palabras incluidas en el artículo parecen ser correctas, la de FUCK como "Fornication Under Consent of the the King" es [completamente falsa](http://www.snopes.com/language/acronyms/fuck.asp). Podría ser la única, pero me hace ser un poco más escéptico hacia la de "yupi".

Comment: ¡Bien descubierto! Siempre vi con escepticismo lo de _FUCK_... Pregunta subsiguiente: ¿cómo se puede decir _caveats_ en castellano? :)

Comment: @fedorqui ¿pegas?

Comment: @fedorqui  _Caveats_ = Advertencias

Comment: SOS tiene su origen en el código morse. Nada que ver con Save Our Souls. El resto del articulo es "para cogerlo con pinzas"

Comment: @roetnig, otras entradas como las de "guay", "KO", "OK", [pantalón](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?pantalo.n), [asesino](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?asesino) parecen ser válidas. Por eso la de "yupi" no sabemos bien dónde cae. Como es lo mejor que tenemos de momento, mejor dejar el post publicado y que sirva para que alguien pueda continuar la investigación.