# ¿Por qué en "primate" la acepción zoológica ha casi desplazado a la de "persona prominente, prócer"?

Tags: sustantivos

La definición actual de [**primate**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UAVYZcl) es:

> 1. adj. Zool. Dicho de un mamífero: De superior organización, plantígrado, con las extremidades terminadas en cinco dedos provistos de uñas, de los cuales el pulgar es oponible a los demás, al menos en los miembros torácicos. U. m. c. s. m., en pl. como taxón.
> 2. m. Personaje distinguido, prócer. U. m. en pl.

Esta segunda y, en mi experiencia, poco usada acepción es la definición inicial y única de la palabra hasta el suplemento de **1947** del diccionario de la RAE.

¿Cómo se ha producido este desplazamiento de las acepciones?

Comment: Estoy viendo una edición hecha ayer mismo en Wikipedia en que un usuario ha sustituido la palabra *primates* por *miembros* (https://es.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Eduardo_Dato&type=revision&diff=100264268&oldid=99924788). La palabra estaba usada con el sentido original, pero seguramente este usuario pensaba que estaba deshaciendo un vandalismo.

Answer (score 5):

Sí, tienes razón respecto a la segunda acepción es la más antigua. Si comprobamos la [etimología de "primate"](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?primate) encontramos que la palabra viene

> del latín *primas, primatis* (primero, primordial, principal).

Esa web explican (y [otras fuentes](http://definicion.de/primate/) lo corroboran) que

> en el siglo XIII se utilizaba el mismo para referirse a aquellas figuras que dentro de la jerarquía de la Iglesia contaban con un rango de nivel superior.

Es decir, que se usaba `primate` con el significado de "primero, primordial, principal", que es la segunda acepción del término (Personaje distinguido, prócer.)

Como explica la primera referencia, [el científico, naturalista, botánico y zoólogo sueco Carlos Linneo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carlos_Linneo) (considerado fundador de la moderna taxonomía, y también se le reconoce como uno de los padres de la ecología) usó el término `primates` en su ordenación taxonómica porque el término significa, precisamente, "primeros" en latín, queriendo

> [...] evidenciar que los monos son los animales más semejantes a los humanos y que, todos juntos son los organismos "primeros" en la escala zoológica o los más completamente desarrollados del reino animal, en una visión fuertemente antropocéntrica, común en su época
>
> <sub>Fuente: [edukavital.blogspot.com : ¿Cuál es el Significado de Primates?](https://edukavital.blogspot.com/2013/05/primates.html)</sub>

Linneo no elaboró su [taxonomía](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carlos_Linneo#Taxonom.C3.ADa) hasta 1731, por lo que la primera acepción del diccionario es, como bien indicas, más moderna que la segunda. Aunque también es raro que no entrase hasta 1947 en el diccionario de la RAE.

Como el español es una lengua viva, es el uso el que hace evolucionar los términos. La RAE recoge y documenta, peor no siempre podemos explicar cómo un término evoluciona, gana popularidad o cae en desuso.

Como conjeturas, puede ser que se usasen más los términos  *primero*, *primordial* o *principal* frente a "primate" por puro capricho de los hablantes, o que para no ser asociado con la acepción zoológica se  favoreciesen otros términos para referirse a los altos cargos eclesiásticos o personas prominentes, lo que terminaría por favorecer el uso de "primate" en su acepción zoológica mucho más que en su significado de "destacado".

En esta web tenemos otros ejemplos de cómo han evolucionado ciertos términos, como por ejemplo

- [¿Por qué “hortera” es, en Madrid, el apodo del mancebo de ciertas tiendas de mercader?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/19127/5481)
- [¿Por qué “yegua” y no “caballa”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/18659/5481)
- [¿De dónde viene la exclamación “yupi”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/20190/5481)
- [¿Por qué las furgonetas de la policía se llaman “lecheras” en España?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/14749/5481)

que reflejan que **la evolución del lenguaje es a veces lógica y a veces caprichosa**.

Comment: Añadiría a esto que la palabra puede haber caído en desuso por contar con variados sinónimos que no aluden a simios, como *prohombre* (que incorpora la idea de precedencia, *pro-*) y *prócer*. En el ámbito eclesiástico se dice hoy *primado* al obispo principal de una jurisdicción, pero la palabra latina era *primas, -atis* y todavía se usa *primate* en este sentido en italiano y en inglés (pronunciado /ˈpraɪmət/).

Answer (score 2):

Yo creo que debe haber habido alguna autocensura que dificultó decir que alguien era un primate. Imagínate aludir a alguien importante con una palabra que también significaba "simio", considerando además la complicación moral que implicó ir aceptando la teoría de la evolución.

Hay una famosa teoría de Geoffrey Leech que distingue siete tipos de significado (en la escuela nos enseñaron dos: el *denotativo* y el *connotativo*). Entre ellos viene al caso aquí el **significado reflejo**, que se refiere a "otro" significado que tiene una palabra, que no corresponde al que se está diciendo en la frase, pero que viene a la mente automáticamente y "contamina" la palabra con algún valor indeseado.

Dependiendo del país, hay palabras claras y precisas que, por su significado reflejo, confunden y suenan mal (no estoy seguro de que los siguientes ejemplos se entiendad en todas partes):

> Dados los resultados, creo que te conviene **abortar** y replantear el experimento.
>
> Tuve que **coger** a mi amiga en brazos para cruzar.
>
> En mi casa hay un **mojón** que indica dónde está la entrada.
>
> Compré una **polla** muy sana, espero que ponga pronto.
>
> Agregamos **preservativo** a la masa.

El último ejemplo muestra cómo una palabra decente y funcional tuvo que abandonar su significado original porque empezó a sonar a condones, y fue desplazada por otras que estaban por ahí disponibles (*preservantes, conservantes*).

Me imagino que con *primate* tuvo que pasar algo similar. La palabra, aunque significara dignamente "principal", empezó a sonar a "mono" y, como esto debe haber sido bastante inaceptable en esos años, fue desplazada por otras palabras disponibles (*procer*, etc.).